# open file dialog return multiple file names (Visual Basic 2010 C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, textbox, openfiledialog

How to make a OpenFileDialog1 object return multiple paths of the selected files to a multi-line textbox?

Comment: Start by setting the [`MultiSelect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.multiselect(v=vs.110).aspx) property to `true`, and look at the example in the docs to see how to get the names of the files selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created some code for you to use:

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
    string[] lines = GetFileNames();

    if (lines != null)
        textBox1.Lines = lines;
}

private string[] GetFileNames()
{
    var dialog = new OpenFileDialog()
    {
        Multiselect = true
    };

    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        return dialog.FileNames;
    else
        return null;
}
```

I hope it helps.